# MVC Error - Requires a model item of type IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, ienumerable

I'm new to both MVC and LinqToSql. I'm trying to create a small application that lists contacts using both technologies.

My Model:

```
public class Contact 
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Range(18, 99)]
    public int? Age { get; set; }
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Phone]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public Gender? Gender { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

public enum Gender { Male, Female }
```

My Controller:

```
public class ContactController : Controller
{
    private string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conStr"].ConnectionString;
    private LinqToSqlDataContext db;

     public ActionResult Index()
     {
        using (db = new LinqToSqlDataContext(conStr))
        {
            var contacts = (IEnumerable)(from c in db.Contacts select c);
            return View(contacts);
        }
    }
```

My View:

```
@model IEnumerable<ContactsApp.Models.Contact>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        ...
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
         ...          
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

When I run this I get the following error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1[ContactsApp.Contact]', but this
>   dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[ContactsApp.Models.Contact]'.

I understand the View expects an IEnumerable parameter. I cast the query to IEnumerable but I'm still getting the error.

I'd appreciate help in understanding what exactly I'm doing wrong and what is the most efficient way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your query returns `IQueryable`

```
(from c in db.Contacts select c) // <-- returns IQueryable
```

You need to convert it to List (which is an `IEnumerable`)

```
using (db = new LinqToSqlDataContext(conStr))
{
    var contacts = db.Contacts.ToList(); // <-- converts the result to List
    return View(contacts);
}
```